# pandas value to find in a dictionary and return key - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

In my pandas data frame column, I need to check if the column has any of the word in the dictionary values, then I should return the key.

```
my_dict = {'woodhill': ["woodhill"],'woodcocks': ["woodcocks"], 'whangateau' : ["whangateau","whangate"],'whangaripo' : ["whangaripo","whangari","whangar"],
              'westmere' : ["westmere"],'western springs': ["western springs","western springs","western spring","western sprin",
"western spri","western spr","western sp","western s"]}
```

I can write a for loop for this, however, I have nearly 1.5 million records in my data frame and the dictionary has more than 100 items and each may have up to 20 values in some case. How do I do this efficiently? Can I create reverse the values as key and key as values in the dictionary to make it fast? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st reverse the dictionary items. # as limited items , so it'll be fast.

2nd create dataframe from dictionary. # instead of searching all keys for each comparison with dataframe, it's best to do join. so for that create dataframe.

3rd make left join from big size dataframe to small size dataframe (in this case dictionary).

Comment: I can't make a join here as my data frame column is not exactly the dictionary value. Column values will be like 'western spring road western spring', 'kings road western spring', 'test value'.

Comment: oh.. then after 1st operation use map with "IN" operation to dataframe. don't forget to use .iloc !! and again while doing "IN" operation do "ANY" for faster performance!!.

Answer (score 2):

you can reverse your dictionary

```
reversed_dict = {val: key for key in my_dict for val in my_dict[key]}
```

and then map with your dataframe

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'col1':['western springs','westerns','whangateau','whangate']})
df['col1'] = df['col1'].map(reversed_dict)
```

Try this code, this may help you.

Comment: Hi Geetha. Thanks for your reply. However my data frame won't be like this. It will be like this - df =pd.DataFrame({col1 :['western springs','western s']}). Sorry I didn't mention this.

Comment: Are you want to replace your column values with dictionary key if dictionary value matches!

Comment: Try reversing your dict and then do mapping